# Arris TG862 - "Connected Devices" page blank or No Data Received

Tags: networking, router, connection

I have an Arris 862G modem/router from Comcast, and have recently been giving static IPs to various devices in my home network. However, after assigning a static IP to one of them (a Surface RT, if that matters), the "Connected Devices" page of the router (after logging into the default gateway in a browser) almost always gives a "No Data Received" error, or simply shows up as a completely blank page. This happens with or without the Surface on. All other pages in the router work perfectly fine. It seems that a lot of other people have had a similar issue with this router, and Comcast has not been helpful.

Does anyone know why this is doing it or how to fix it? Can I fix it without a factory reset, or is that necessary?

And yes, I tried restarting it. Nothing changed.

EDIT: Turning on and then turning off one of the other devices (an HP G72 laptop) made it work again, but then it just stopped after a while. Further tests with various machines show that connecting/disconnecting something "fixes" it, and then it randomly stops later after another change.

EDIT again: Now nothing seems to be able to make it work again.

Comment: BTW, the site told me "The errors tag is not allowed." What does this mean? If it's not allowed, then why is it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work these modems daily with another isp...

I instantly reccomend trading that box out for a non-wifi arris Mta and provide your own router.

The reliability of those 852/862 combos are awful. The connected devices section is buggy and intermittent. It will drop devices off that list frequently, add 169.254 addresses to it's device table, and flood the same list with incorrect mac addresses.

Sorry about the rant.

A factory is likely to resolve your issue for a time.
And.
When you restart the device, are you taking out the battery backup as well? I'd assume that if you called Comcast they had you try that.

Comment: It's never had a battery to begin with. And yes, I know this router is awful, and plan on getting a new one soon, but I was wondering if there was a simple fix I could do. I guess I'm stuck doing a factory reset and going back to the two static IPs I had set, as I never had any problems getting into the page with only two.